# Rails 3: ActiveRecord vs. DataMapper (vs. ???) for Legacy MySQL Databases

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, datamapper

Which ORM is best to use with a new Rails 3 app against a legacy MySQL 5.1 database? I do not expect to ever run a migration against this database (though the schema may change from time to time), but I will certainly be writing to it.

Comment: Can you share a bit of the schema?

Comment: Sorry, it is the intellectual property of a client, so I can't share it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I may be biased towards DataMapper, but I think DM is generally a good option for integrating with legacy databases.

- DM allows you to map meaningful model
  and property names to cryptic legacy
  table and column naming conventions.
  It allows you to do so either on a
  per model/property, or an app wide basis.
- DM supports lazy properties, that will only be fetched when actually accessed.
- DM has seamless support for composite primary keys.
- DM only cares about the properties (columns) you explicitly
  declare in your models. Other columns will never be touched or read.
- DM works nice with foreign key constraints in your database and with the help of [dm-constraints](http://github.com/datamapper/dm-constraints) it also supports creating them.

There's some documentation on http://datamapper.org/docs/legacy too.

Answer (score 5):

There is also the dm-types-legacy library (https://github.com/postmodern/dm-types-legacy) which provides common DM Types for mapping in oddly formatted data (Numeric IP Addresses, HTML/URI encoded text, Date/Time strings).

Comment: Does any of this work with datetime_select? For example, I am trying to update a datetime field and it fails because of this: "published_at(1i)"=>"2010", "published_at(2i)"=>"11", "published_at(3i)"=>"14", "published_at(4i)"=>"07", "published_at(5i)"=>"59"